# What packaging type to use for integration test module in Maven

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have a maven project which contains integration test solely. It defaults to a jar package and a jar file will be created, which is not necessary.

How can I config the module so that no jar package is created?

Comment: Just don't run the task/goal that packages the application as a JAR file.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a separate project, just don't call `install` or `deploy` but e.g. `verify`.

If this a module of a multi module project, you need to configure the install and deploy plugin to be skipped, for which you can use the `<skip>` parameter.